# Merging objects based on multiple matching keys - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm struggling with something that seems like it should be trivial. I have an array of objects:

```
const vehicles = [
{
    "sku": "1234",
    "year": "2004",
    "make": "Chevrolet",
    "model": "Avalanche",
},
{
    "sku": "1234",
    "year": "2006",
    "make": "Chevrolet",
    "model": "Avalanche",
},
{
    "sku": "1234",
    "year": "2009",
    "make": "Chevrolet",
    "model": "Silverado 1500",
},
{
    "sku": "1234",
    "year": "2006",
    "make": "Chevrolet",
    "model": "Silverado 1500",
}]
```

I would like to match on `sku`, `make`, and `model` and flatten the objects to have a final state of:

```
const mutatedVehicles = [
  {
    "sku": "1234",
    "years": ["2004", "2006"],
    "make": "Chevrolet",
    "model": "Avalanche",
  },
  {
    "sku": "1234",
    "years": ["2009", "2006"],
    "make": "Chevrolet",
    "model": "Silverado 1500"
  }]
```

I've actually worked with this in Python initially using dictionaries, but ultimately prefer some of the methods available in JS. I've tried using Array.forEach, Object.assign, and a few other methods and have come up short.

**EDIT**: I was asked to share some of the code I had tried - it's Python, not JS, as that's where I initially started.

```
def match_props(f, x):
    if f['sku'] == x['sku'] and f['year'] != x['year'] and f['make'] == x['make'] and f['model'] == x['model']:
        return True
    else:
        return False

fitments = [
    {
        "sku": "1234",
        "year": "2004",
        "make": "Chevrolet",
        "model": "Avalanche",
        "drive": "",
    },
    {
        "sku": "1234",
        "year": "2009",
        "make": "Chevrolet",
        "model": "Silverado 1500",
        "drive": "",
    },
    {
        "sku": "1234",
        "year": "2006",
        "make": "Chevrolet",
        "model": "Silverado 1500",
        "drive": "",
    },
]

merged = []

for f1 in fitments:
    pMerge = {}
    for f2 in fitments:
        if match_props(f1, f2):
            pMerge = {
                    "sku": f1['sku'],
                    "make": f1['make'],
                    "model": f1['model'],
                    "drive": f1['drive'],
                    "years": [y for y in [f1['year'], f2['year']]]
            }
        else:
            pMerge = f2
    if pMerge not in merged:
        merged.append(pMerge)


print(merged)
```

Comment: Could you also post up the js you have tried for us to checkout?

Comment: No problem - it's Python though - I was using stackblitz for my JS and did not save before I navigated away from page - my apologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```js
const vehicles  = [{"sku":"1234","year":"2004","make":"Chevrolet","model":"Avalanche"},{"sku":"1234","year":"2006","make":"Chevrolet","model":"Avalanche"},{"sku":"1234","year":"2009","make":"Chevrolet","model":"Silverado 1500"},{"sku":"1234","year":"2006","make":"Chevrolet","model":"Silverado 1500"}];

let result = Object.values(vehicles.reduce((a,{sku, year, make, model}) => {
  let id = sku + "_" + make + "_" + model;
  if(a[id]) a[id].years.push(year)
  else a[id] = {sku, make, model, years : [year]}
  return a;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I like this answer, but be careful using Object.values because its not supported in IE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

Comment: @jman93 I think pretty much everyone uses a transpiler nowadays so you don't really have to care about compatibility.

Comment: Maybe, somethings don't transpile and somethings do.  Someone would just have to test it

Comment: We're all in luck, as this would be backend - likely a Node.js REST API.

Comment: @Nikhil Aggarwal this is great - I had actually toyed with the idea of using an identifier composed of the different keys, but unfortunately never executed it.

Comment: @Smitty - Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Although this answer overlaps with the one from Nikhil Aggarwal, it is enough different to show it.  Instead of fixing the key fields, it focuses on the ones (here just `year`, but would be easy to extend to others) that have multiple values.

```js
const collect = (vehicles) => Object.values(vehicles.reduce((vs, v) => {
  const {year, ...veh} = v
  const key = JSON.stringify(veh);
  const vehicle = vs[key] || (vs[key] = {years: [], ...veh})
  vehicle.years.push(year)
  return vs
}, {}))

const vehicles = [{"make": "Chevrolet", "model": "Avalanche", "sku": "1234", "year": "2004"}, {"make": "Chevrolet", "model": "Avalanche", "sku": "1234", "year": "2006"}, {"make": "Chevrolet", "model": "Silverado 1500", "sku": "1234", "year": "2009"}, {"make": "Chevrolet", "model": "Silverado 1500", "sku": "1234", "year": "2006"}]

console.log(collect(vehicles))
```